# Why is my SPAM served so slow?

Tags: support, spam

I mean, often there is a "1 question with new activity" button. I click it *immediately* when it appears for me, and whoa, question is already deleted. It's pretty irritating - if post gets deleted before info is shown on my screen, server should stop that info, right?

Posting here and not on meta stackexchange, because I see it only on Drupal Answers.

Comment: Actually, it should happen in any site where you can see deleted posts, for what I understand it. It happened that clicking on that _1 question with new activity_ I could see a question that was automatically deleted because I destroyed the user account as spammer, and that question was not even shown with the usual background deleted questions have.

Comment: @kiamlaluno the point is, an instant later question is not even on the list at all. Weird. And i only see deleted posts here, so that explains a bit.